# Finding the shortest vector in a subspace of an inner product space

Tags: real-analysis, inner-products

In the inner product space $L^2$[$0,1$], find a shortest vector to $f(x)=sin(πx)$ in the subspace $W=[a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2|a_0,a_1,a_2∈$**R**$]$. How does one prove that the vector found is a shortest one?

Comment: Write down the distance between an element of $W$ and $f$.  That is a function of the unknowns $a_0$, $a_1$, and $a_2$.  Minimize that function (it's a calculus problem).

Comment: *or* use Gram-Schmidt to find an orthonormal basis of $W$.  Use that basis to find the projection of $f$ onto $W$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Gram-Schmidt process. What is the distance formula between an element of W and f?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but if the question is about minimizing the distance in $L^2[0,1]$, and you don't know how to compute the distance in $L^2[0,1]$, what kind of help do you expect on this problem?  Please do a little bit of work to understand the problem.

Comment: Is it just [($sin(πx)$)^2+$(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2)^2$]^(1/2)

Comment: @JasonSmith: in $L^2(0,1)$ with the usual inner product, the distance between $f$ and $g$ is $\|f-g\|_2$, i.e. $\sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}(f(x)-g(x))^2\,dx}$.

Comment: My apologies, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that [the shifted Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Shifted_Legendre_polynomials) $P_n(2x-1)$ give an orthogonal base of $L^2(0,1)$ with the usual inner product:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}P_n(2x-1)P_m(2x-1)\,dx = \frac{\delta(n,m)}{2n+1} $$
so the projection of $\sin(\pi x)$ on the subspace generated by $\{1,x,x^2\}$ is given by $c_0 P_0(2x-1)+c_1 P_1(2x-1)+c_2 P_2(2x-1)$ where:
$$ c_i = (2i+1)\int_{0}^{1}\sin(\pi x)P_i(2x-1)\,dx $$
so the projection is given by:
$$ p(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}+\frac{10(\pi^2-12)}{\pi^3}P_2(2x-1) $$
and the squared distance between $\sin(\pi x)$ and $p(x)$ is given by:
$$ \|\sin(\pi x)-p(x)\|_2^2 = \sum_{n>2} (2n+1) c_n^2 = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{2880}{\pi ^6}+\frac{480}{\pi ^4}-\frac{24}{\pi ^2}\approx 3\cdot 10^{-4}$$
that is minimal since $p(x)$ and $\sin(\pi x)-p(x)$ are orthogonal.